# Xcode - no XCFramework found

Tags: swift, xcode, sdk

```
   There is no XCFramework found at '/Users/alexanderchoi/Desktop/VaxPass/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework'.
```

I am getting this error when I run. I have done pod deintegrate and pod install and my pods seem there. The frameworks are red, which is a bit weird but maybe because I was transferred this project from another computer.

Any help will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that in my pods file, GoogleMobileAds didn't have some of the files, so I went to a GitHub, containing GOogleMobileAds pod and copied the missing files.

Answer (score 15):

If this happens while using SwiftPM resetting the package caches in Xcode solved the issue for me.

`File > Packages > Reset Package Caches`

Comment: In my case, using SPM, the xcframework is pointing to my local DerivedData, which makes the build fail on CI and any other machine. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: This process takes quite a while, like 10 min (processing indexing). Not sure why so long?

Comment: This fixed the error for me. In my case, it happened with the upgrade from Xcode 14 to 15.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this while building via xcodebuild. Changing the schema's Build Configuration to Release, then back to Debug fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just added the frameworks manually in GENERAL tab and it worked! They were missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove and add the framework `GoogleInteractiveMediaAds` again in the General tab in Xcode for the compiler to rebuild it again after I removed my derived data.